# Cross-fade or dissolve between two C4Images

Tags: ios, c4

How would I do some sort of animation or transition between two C4Images?

I have a setup like this:

```
C4Image * img1 = [[C4Image alloc] initWithRawData:rawData width:width height:height];
C4Image * img2 = [[C4Image alloc] initWithRawData:rawData width:width height:height];

[self.canvas addImage:img1];
// insert magic here to trigger transition
[self.canvas addImage:img2];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do a transition is:

```
image1.animationDuration = 1.0f;
image1.image = image2;
```

You can find a snippet here that crossfades an image to a new image 1 second after launching the app:

https://gist.github.com/C4Code/5074430

Comment: Wow! that was easy! So, if I wanted to have the animation go between the two states I would use the bitmask animation flags?

Comment: Yes, you can change the animation setting with flags. What this technique does is actually change the internal image presented by image1. If you want to be able to switch between images, I suggest having an image1, image2, and a third image to use as a kind of container whose contents you can continuously change back and forth.